# How can I write SQL query with alias in eloquent laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I spend all day to try how write a SQL query in eloquent. I know I can use raw if I have to, but I'm curious is there any way to do that?

My raw SQL is:

```
SELECT *
FROM  
    (SELECT 1 as own, id, up_date, top_list_end_date 
     FROM advertisements 
     WHERE top_list_end_date > now()
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 as own, id, up_date, top_list_end_date 
     FROM advertisements  
     WHERE top_list_end_date IS NULL) a
ORDER BY own, up_date DESC
```

In Laravel I am trying:

```
$groupA = $adv->where('top_list_end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
$groupA->select('*')
        ->selectSub(function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('1');
        }, 'own');
        
$groupB = $restAdv->whereNull('top_list_end_date');
$groupB->select('*')
        ->selectSub(function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('2');
        }, 'own');
        
$result = $groupA->unionAll($groupB);

$result->orderBy('own', 'desc')->orderBy('up_date', 'desc')->get();
```

Is there any way to create the same select in eloquent?

Comment: Or a simpler query `SELECT IF(ISNULL(top_list_date),2,1) as own, id, up_date , top_list_end_date FROM advertisements WHERE top_list_end_date > now()
   OR top_list_end_date IS NULL ORDER BY own, up_date desc`

Comment: Can you write your purpose for writing a query like this?

Comment: in one query i need take all values but first should be sorting by up_date from group 1 (own 1) and rest from group 2 (own 2) this is to show the list of items but on top should be lits with promo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eloquent way will be something like this:

```
$first = DB::table('advertisements')
            ->select(DB::raw('"1" AS own'), 'id', 'up_date', 'top_list_end_date')
            ->whereRaw('top_list_end_date > NOW()')

$advertisements = DB::table('advertisements')
            ->select(DB::raw('"2" AS own'), 'id', 'up_date', 'top_list_end_date')
            ->whereNull('top_list_end_date')
            ->unionAll($first)
            ->orderBy('own', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('up_date', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

For reference, please see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#unions)

Laravel `unionAll` has the same signature as `union`.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use SQL query in laravel. you can use query builder like

```
DB::raw();
```

or

```
DB::select();
```

and if you want to use SQL query with alias, just write like this.

```
$users = DB::table('your_table_name AS t')
       ->select('t.id AS uid')
       ->get();
```

Hope this answer help you.

Best of luck:)